# Using MS Graph API C# SDK for Reply To email

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, microsoft-graph-api

I have been using MS Graph SDK in my asp.net core 6 app for some time now. However, I am not able to use the reply to example from the MS docs as it states "Me" type or namespace cannot be found. If I added the latest MS Graph and MS Graph Core nuget packets it breaks all my other MS Graph code I have been using for months (onedrive and some email inbox stuff). Not sure why it would just fail to work for this one example. I also never had to officially install those packages as ms graph nuget package (4.34.0) falls under the dependency of microsoft.identity.web.microsoftgraph nuget package i already had installed for logging in/authentication.

```
            var requestBody = new Microsoft.Graph.Me.Messages.Item.Reply.ReplyPostRequestBody
        {
            Message = new Message
            {
                ToRecipients = new List<Recipient>
                {
                    new Recipient
                    {
                        EmailAddress = new EmailAddress
                        {
                            Address = "samanthab@contoso.onmicrosoft.com",
                            Name = "Samantha Booth",
                        },
                    },
                    new Recipient
                    {
                        EmailAddress = new EmailAddress
                        {
                            Address = "randiw@contoso.onmicrosoft.com",
                            Name = "Randi Welch",
                        },
                    },
                },
            },
            Comment = "Samantha, Randi, would you name the group please?",
        };
        await _graphServiceClient.Me.Messages["{message-id}"].Reply.PostAsync(requestBody);
```

Comment: Try "this" instead of "Me".  "Me" is vbnet reference to current class while "this" is the c# equivalent.

Comment: That did not work unfortunately.

Comment: Could you clarify which version of SDK do you use?

Comment: I am using 4.34

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SDK v4 then you can use this snippet to create a reply

```
var message = new Message
    {
        ToRecipients = new List<Recipient>
        {
            new Recipient
            {
                EmailAddress = new EmailAddress
                {
                    Address = "samanthab@contoso.onmicrosoft.com",
                    Name = "Samantha Booth",
                },
            },
            new Recipient
            {
                EmailAddress = new EmailAddress
                {
                    Address = "randiw@contoso.onmicrosoft.com",
                    Name = "Randi Welch",
                },
            },
        }
    };
var comment = "Samantha, Randi, would you name the group please?";

await client.Me.Messages["{message-id}"].Reply(message, comment).Request().PostAsync();
```

Comment: I am using v4.34 so I will test this out.

Comment: So are those considered new recipients such that if you didnt add any then it would just reply to those in the original email?

Comment: So I am able to build without errors however I do target a certain shared email address with await _graphServiceClient.Users[EmailAccount].Messages[MessageId].Reply(message, comment).Request().PostAsync(); instead. I do get a weird error though that says Code: ErrorInvalidRequest\nMessage: The OData request is not supported.\nClientRequestId:blahblahblah

Comment: FIgured it out. Issue with my message ID. Thank you so much for your help. Weird how v5 has so many breaking changes. Might stick to v4 for a while.